# Access - transpose some column data into row records

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I would like to apply a similar function like this:
["Transposing" some columns with ID fields into rows while copying the other data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253006/transposing-some-columns-with-id-fields-into-rows-while-copying-the-other-data)

but in these conditions:

Table:

```
A | B | 1 | 3 | 5 | 2|

C | D | 8 | 5 | 4 | 7|
```

into a table like this:

```
A | B | 1 |

A | B | 3 |

A | B | 5 |

A | B | 2 |

C | D | 8 |

C | D | 5 |

C | D | 4 |

C | D | 7 |
```

Is this possible by modifying the quoted function? Or a solution in Access is easier?

Comment: Why is **A | B | 2 |** missing *??*

Comment: It was a mistake. Post is edited now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, consider an SQL union query which can be run in either Excel or Access, both using the Jet/ACE engine (Windows .dll files):

```sql
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM TableOrSheet$Name
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col4
FROM TableOrSheet$Name
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col5
FROM TableOrSheet$Name
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col6
FROM TableOrSheet$Name
```

Answer (score 1):

With data in columns **A** through **F**, pick any cell, say **H3**, and enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0))
```

and copy down.  In **I3** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0))
```

and copy down.  In **J3** enter:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$F$100,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0),IF(MOD(ROWS($1:1),4)=0,4,MOD(ROWS($1:1),4)))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for solution but it is useful for a constant number of columns.
Unfortunately, the source table has variable filled in columns : 
5 colums for row 1; 15 columns for row 2; 8 columns for row 3, etc

Comment: @Arnold  Thanks for the feedback..................with variable columns, I would use a VBA macro to build the second table.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with VBA scripts but I'll try :)

Comment: @Arnold  Excellent!...............if you hit any snags, update your post with the code your have written and we will assist you.